# simplification of $W(x\cdot e^{a+x})$

Tags: lambert-w

Is it possible to simplify $W(x\cdot e^{a+x})$?

Because $W(x\cdot e^{x})=x$

So I was wondering if it was possible to simplify this expression.

Comment: Assuming $a$ is real, this would be the same as simplifying $W(cxe^x)$ for $c>0$ (I cannot think of anything helpful for this case)

Comment: Really? Is it impossible to find a method to remove the lambert w term? In any case?

Comment: I dont think that there will be a simplification. Because there is a linear scaling factor $k=e^a$ which shifts the value of the function, again as Lambert-$W$. This is basically true for any shifting. Especially, $W$ is non-linear and one cannot separate it. But, one can approximate it and find some approximate simplifications. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to say no, this is not simplify-able.

You can however attempt to obtain an expansion via logarithms:

$$W(x)=\ln(x)-\ln(\ln(x))+\mathcal O(\ln(\ln(\ln(x))))$$

So,

> $$W(xe^{a+x})=a+x+\ln(x)-\ln(a+x+\ln(x))+\mathcal O(\ln(\ln(x)))$$

as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: there is no $n$ defined, anyways.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I've searched my screen for the letter $n$, but you and the related links are the only ones mentioning the variable $n$.  Could you clarify on what you meant?

Comment: I do use glasses but... $n\rightarrow\infty$.. and now it is $x\rightarrow\infty$ magic!)

Comment: xD Funny thing is [this happened to me just this morning!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380261/what-is-the-tangent-line-to-y-e-fracx2-through-0-0?noredirect=1#comment4907334_2380261).